# How to deal with large infinite scroll page while scraping?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape comments in a website. After some point where there are so many comments(around 10000), the headless chrome driver becomes very slow. Is there any workaround (or online tool or whatever, can be non-free and even non-python) which can scroll to the bottom and save the page for me? My problem seems to be memory/performance problem though my computer is generally fast (16GB ram) and 8GB is free when program is running. The running time exponentially grows.

A bit more info if that helps: I'm using selenium and the important lines of codes are as follows:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import selenium as se
options = se.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
driver.get(url)
body = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
for i in range(10**4)
    body.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: @SwaroopHumane I've seen that article before and more or less have it in my code . The problem is performance and memory not how to scroll in selenium.